# How do I generate this u with acute accent and under horn?

Tags: fonts, symbols, unicode

Below is the photo of the word that uses this letter. The language is [Jemez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jemez_language), fwiw.

Is there such a unicode character? What is the name of that "thing" under the letter? How do I obtain it in latex?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a "u" with acute accent and [ogonek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogonek). It doesn't seem to exist in unicode, but it can be obtained by stacking a u with ogonek (U+0173) and an acute accent.

If you use a unicode-based engine, you can directly use the symbol "ų́" in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
ų́
\end{document}
```

If you use pdfLaTeX, you can use `\k` for the ogonek and `\'` for the acute accent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\k{\'u}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the name of that "thing" under the letter?

This [subscript curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic#Types) looks like an [ogonek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogonek). It may also be [a coma bellow or single quotation mark bellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Comma_variants), or even a [cedilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla).

> Is there such a unicode character?

Per se no. No such precomposed character, but Unicode know and allow all [diacritical marks via combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges).

> How do I obtain it in latex?

If it's ogonek, as I think,

- with LaTeX2e alone and T1 encoding, you can use `\k{u}` or `\textogonekcentered{u}`
- with [tipa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIPA_%28software%29) package and T3 encoding, you can use `\textpolhook{u}` or something like (not sure but I think it's [sampa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMPA_chart)...) `\textipa{u_=}`

Of course, to combine with the [apex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) too. e.g. `\k{\'u}`.